# Friendly robot is stalking me and won't leave

Tags: bug, area-51, cancel

Take a look on this friendly robot:
[image]

Looks innocent, right? Well, he is not.

I just went over the list of question on a [proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating?tab=active&phase=definition#tab-top), the home of that robot and tried to upvote a question I liked:

> [image]

The robot appeared and explained to me I actually can't vote. Trying my luck, I clicked again. The dialog re-appeared as expected.

Time to give up, I wanted to read the other questions. I clicked the "cancel" in the dialog. Nothing happens. I clicked outside the dialog. Nothing happened. The robot is there to stay, and won't leave until I reload the page!

I know, I misbehaved by clicking twice, but still... do I deserve such extreme punishment? Can it please be closed when clicking "cancel" even if I clicked more than once?

Comment: "do I deserve such extreme punishment?" Almost assuredly. Not for *that* offense, but I'm sure there's something!

Comment: Maybe it realized that you're under aged so voting on questions about sex is not allowed? Grow up!

Comment: @rene you got me! ;)

Comment: By the way, anyone can find a suitable name for that robot? :)

Comment: It's name isn't `Beep!` then?

Comment: @rene nah, too simple. "Beeper" in the least but it's missing something. Hmm... what about "Beepicorn", the beeping unicorn?

Comment: Anyone else find it amusing that the dating and relationship page can't be voted on because it is in a commitment?

Comment: @TravisJ haha! Yes; I hadn't noticed that!

Comment: @TravisJ wait until it will get a private moment with Beta! :D