# Don't ask me to follow my own site proposal everytime I visit it using the quick-link

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Area 51 won't remember who I am when I click on the sharing link.
I know it's a link made for sharing to other users but could it check if I am already following this proposal before taking the whole top bar to tell me to follow.

Refreshing the page won't make it go away, clicking on it, or elsewhere won't make it go away either.
**It just won't go away.**

When I go the manually (Click on the site, click on my name, search my proposal for this one) :

> [image]

When I use the insta-super-quicky link :

> [image]

It is way faster using the second option since I have the quick-link in my profile description. Also I am logged in on Area51 When I get this welcome message.

Comment: Makes sense, +1 but count your blessing... I was [haunted by a stalker robot that won't go away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210788/152859)! Also, now I understand [this column](http://i.stack.imgur.com/17FNI.png), always wondered how it can increase.